# How to do console.log debugging on dependency packages with next.js

Tags: debugging, next.js

Running `next dev`,  I can put a breakpoint in a browser (for example chrome) on a .js file at the following path, and the breakpoint is hit (this file is part of a package that is a dependency of the project I'm working on):

```
webpack-internal://
.
node_modules
ra-core/esm
dataProvider
useGetMany.js
```

However, I'd like instead to do some console.log debugging in that file.  As it happens that file is originally a TypeScript file - but I don't mind whether I'm editing generated .js or the original .ts

The problem is that my `console.log`s don't seem to take effect.  Having edited every copy of useGetMany.js/useGetMany.ts in node_modules, restarted the dev server, and done a hard-refresh, I still don't see my edit show up in the .js source code I see browsing through `webpack-internal://` in the browser (I see this both in chrome and firefox).  Nor do I see my `console.log` output.

These are the files I edited:

```
node_modules/ra-core/esm/dataProvider/useGetMany.js
node_modules/ra-core/lib/dataProvider/useGetMany.js
node_modules/ra-core/src/dataProvider/useGetMany.ts
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I do `console.log` debugging here?

Answer (score 0):

Next development server renders files on server side by default, so `console.log` should output on the terminal, where the development server was started.

If it is still not outputting the log, you can try to remove the `.next` cache folder first.

Comment: This was a long time ago now but: did you see the part about me hitting the relevant code in the browser debugger?

Comment: Yes, this is for the code which is being served, it may be cached code in `.next` folder.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.  What I'm saying is: if I hit the relevant code in the browser debugger, it seems clear that the explanation for the lack of debug log output in the browser is not that that code runs on the server.